# Question about Remapping

Tags: ros, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the tutorial of "Using rqt_console and roslaunch", in the node of "mimic" of package "turtlesim", it remaps the topics "/input/pose" and "/output/command_velocity" by just remapping "input" to "/turtlesim1/turtle1" and "output" to "/turtlesim2/turtle1", which i.e. just remaps the base name of the topic rather than the global name.

However, it seems this method fails to work for the node of "turtle_teleop_key". In the launch file, I remap the topic "turtle1/command_veolcity" by remapping "turtle1" to "turtle2", but the topic lists still show "turtle1/command_velocity". When I fix the launch file by remapping "turtle1/command_velocity" to "turtle2/command_velocity", the topics lists finally show the change.

Can someone know figure out the difference between the base name and global name when remapping topics?

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113391/question-about-remapping/) by [Dave Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10276/dave-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on how the node is designed. If it is designed such that it remaps specific names. If the node internally uses a specific string and then builds the higherarchy below it they will remap with the higher level remapping. Otherwise you need to remap each element by its full name.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0